# String replaceAll with conditions

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I am not good in regular expressions and I need help in replacing the string.

```
String str = "Name_XYZ_";
       str = "XYZ_NAME_";
```

So how can I replace `"Name_"` or `"_NAME_"` from above two strings with empty string?
The conditions are `"Name"` can be in any case and it can be at `index 0` or at any index but `preceded by "_"`.

So far I tried,

```
String replacedString = str.replaceAll("(?i)Name_", ""); // This is not correct.
```

This is not the homework. I am working on XML file that needs such kind of processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String replacedString = str.replaceAll("(?i)(?:^|_)name_", "");
```

You were close. What you have to do is *either* [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `name` to the beginning of the string (with `^`) *or* require an underscore there. I also changed `Name` to `name`, because why mix lower and upper case, if you are treating the pattern case-insenstively anyway. Note that `?:` is just an optimization (and a good practice). It suppresses [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) which you don't need in this case.

If you want to improve your regex skills, I can highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: I did. I would have vote up this answer but don't have reputations to do so. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using .NET's regex instead of Java's, but in that context `(_?Name_)` should work.

Comment: That will (in both languages) also remove `Name` if it appears somewhere in the string and is not preceded by `_`.